# dataNucleus enhancement runtime error: dnSetid NoSuchMethodError

Tags: datanucleus

dataNucleus 5.1.1: dnSetid NoSuchMethodError

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Foo {

    @Transient
    public Long getId() {
        ...
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        ...
    }
}

@Entity
public class Bar extends Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="gen")
    @TableGenerator(name="gen", ...)
    public Long getId() {
       ...
    }
}
```

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method dnSetid(Long) in class com.example.Bar

```
    at com.example.Bar.dnCopyKeyFieldsFromObjectId(Unknown Source:15)

    at com.example.Bar.dnNewInstance(Unknown Source:10)

    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.EnhancementHelper.newInstance(EnhancementHelper.java:178)

at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.initialiseForHollow(StateManagerImpl.java:373)

at org.datanucleus.state.ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.newForHollow(ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.java:113)

    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.findObject(ExecutionContextImpl.java:3194)

    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.PersistentClassROF.findObjectWithIdAndLoadFields(PersistentClassROF.java:458)

    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.PersistentClassROF.getObject(PersistentClassROF.java:364)

    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.nextResultSetElement(ForwardQueryResult.java:180)

    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult$QueryResultIterator.next(ForwardQueryResult.java:408)

    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.processNumberOfResults(ForwardQueryResult.java:136)

    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.advanceToEndOfResultSet(ForwardQueryResult.java:164)

    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult.closingConnection(ForwardQueryResult.java:290)

    at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractQueryResult.disconnect(AbstractQueryResult.java:105)

    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.AbstractRDBMSQueryResult.disconnect(AbstractRDBMSQueryResult.java:251)

    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JPQLQuery$2.managedConnectionPreClose(JPQLQuery.java:654)

    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:532)

    at org.datanucleus.store.connection.AbstractManagedConnection.release(AbstractManagedConnection.java:83)

    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.release(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:371)

    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JPQLQuery.performExecute(JPQLQuery.java:730)

    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1966)

    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithMap(Query.java:1873)
```

dnSetid should be added by enhancement. Decompiled Bar.class: there is no such method. It contains dnGetid() and other methods dn****.

Comment: Your "Foo" methods are not valid Java Bean signatures. setXXX takes an argument. Having a getter in subclass needs a setter. Also, marking a property as NOT persisted cannot be overridden later on in an inheritance tree.

Comment: corrected Foo.setId(Long), it is typo. For the subclass Bar, setter should be inherited from its parent class Foo. Transient properties can be overridden in subclasses. this code works well for EclipseLink weaving.

Comment: Nope, the JPA spec does NOT say that you can suddenly make some property persistent further down an inheritance tree. In the same vain, you cannot make a property non-persistent in a subclass when already persistent in a superclass.

Comment: From my experiments with EclipseLInk, transient properties can be overriden, but persistent properties can not be overridden to be transient in subclasses. But AttributeOverride can.  From developer's perspective, they should in both way.

Comment: And what is in EclipseLink is not necessarily in the JPA spec, just like what is in DataNucleus extends the JPA spec in areas.

Comment: Perhaps if you override BOTH getter and setter in the subclass? though I'd agree with Billy Frost that such making of a property persistent in a subclass when not persistent in a superclass is non-portable (and that is especially when it is an `@Id` property)

Answer (score 2):

The only way of overriding is to override BOTH getter AND setter.
Likely the enhancer relies on both being there, whether it is for a defined property or an overridden property.